# Showing that group of orientation preserving isometries of Icosahedron is a simple group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry, symmetric-groups, polyhedra

Let $G$ denote the group of orientation preserving isometries of Icosahedron. To prove the claim, I have shown that

> 1. $\nexists \  N \ \triangleleft \ G$ such that $|N|=5.$
> 2. $\nexists \  N \ \triangleleft \ G$ such that $|N|=3.$
> 3. $\nexists \  N \ \triangleleft \ G$ such that $|N|=2.$

I know the following:

> 1. Rotation around a vertex gives a subgroup of order 5.
> 2. Rotation around the center of a face gives a subgroup of order 3.
> 3. Rotation around the midpoint of an edge gives a subgroup of order 2.

We have $|G|=60=2^2\times 3\times 5.$ What more do I need to show to conclude that $G$ is simple? Is it that I have to show there are no normal subgroup of order $4,6,10,12,15,20,30$? Is there a general theorem that can be useful in my case? I would be glad to know in that case.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, so as I understood from what you have written, you want me to show that $G\cong A_5$, and use the fact that $A_5$ is simple to conclude $G$ is simple. Is this correct?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, my problem is: I am only trying to fill in the missing gap in my argument to conclude that $G$ is simple. By some other construction I know $G\cong A_5.$ But I want to show that $G$ is simple by showing there are no non-trivial proper normal subgroups in $G$. What is the best / concise way to do this?

Comment: Yeah, that was my plan. So I wasted an hour drawing a picture of five tetrahedrons sitting inside a dodecahedron. Oh well. They don't form as nice a picture as I thought, so I'm deleting the previous comments.

Comment: Can you give me some hint on my question? : )

Comment: *I am only trying to fill in the missing gap in my argument*. But the list of numbers you gave is too big to call a "gap." You also seem to want something as group-theoretic as possible; likely you'll need to show $G\cong A_5$ and then invoke the proof $A_5$ is simple.

Comment: @blue, okay. Let my try to make my question clearer: I know that all the orientation preserving isometries of Icosahedron are of the order 2 or 3 or 5. I have shown that neither of the cyclic groups of these orders can be normal. However, to show that $G$ is simple, I need to show that $\nexists$ any normal subgroup in $G$. Is there any theorem that allows me to conclude that $G$ is simple without having to check for all the possiblities mentioned above. I could use your technique, but I am only trying to deduce without using the fact that $A_5$ is simple.

Comment: I never said to use the fact that $A_5$ is simple, I said to invoke the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group of order $60$ with no normal subgroups of order $2$, $3$, or $5$. In each of the following cases, suppose that $H \unlhd G$ were a normal subgroup of order $n$:

1) $n = 10, 15, 20, 30$: $H$ has a normal Sylow $5$-subgroup $P_5$, so $P_5 \text{ char } H \unlhd G \implies P_5 \unlhd G$.

2) $n = 6$: Same argument as in (1), considering a (normal) Sylow $3$-subgroup of $H$.

3) $n = 12$: Either $H$ has a normal Sylow $3$-subgroup, which would be normal in $G$ (contradiction), or $H$ has a normal Sylow $2$-subgroup, which is then normal in $G$. Thus it suffices to show the last case:

4) $n = 4$: Then $H = [G,G]$ (since $G/H$ has order $15$, hence is cyclic $\implies [G,G] \le H$, and $|[G,G]| \ne 1, 2$). If $P_5$ is a Sylow $5$-subgroup of $G$, then $HP_5$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $20$. But $[G,G] = H \le HP_5$, so $HP_5$ is normal in $G$, impossible by (1).

Comment: what is char? (I am quite new to group theory. I still have to understand Sylow's theorems.)

Comment: @ush: $\text{char}$ stands for characteristic subgroup, which means fixed under all automorphisms. The result I am using is: if $K$ is characteristic in $H$ and $H$ is normal in $G$, then $K$ is normal in $G$. If a Sylow $p$-subgroup is normal, then it is characteristic (since it is even unique)

Comment: Please clarify two more things. 1) Why is the first case true? Why do we have $P_5$ normal if $n=10,15,20,30$? 2) What does the notation $[G,G]$ mean? Thanks!

Comment: 1) If $n = 10$ (resp. $15$), then a Sylow $5$-subgroup has index 2 (resp. 3), hence is normal. For $n = 20$, normality of $P_5$ follows from Sylow's theorem. For $n = 30$, every group of order $30$ has a subgroup of order $15$, and their Sylow $5$-subgroups are the same. 2) $[G,G] = \langle g^{-1}h^{-1}gh \mid g, h \in G \rangle $ is the commutator subgroup of $G$

Comment: okay. wonderful!

Comment: in general, is this how we show any finite group $G$ is simple? Namely, by looking at all the possible orders of subgroups, and showing that none of them can be normal? Are there more efficient ways?

Comment: @ush: As far as I know this is not a typical argument - as can be seen, it is very ad-hoc and number-specific. Moreover, it is generally not (any longer) of interest to [show that a finite group is simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups)

Comment: everything went well except one thing: how does it follow that $HP_5$ is normal in $G$ from what you wrote before the claim.

Comment: @ush: Any subgroup of $G$ that contains the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ is automatically normal in $G$. If you have not seen this fact before, you may try to prove it yourself - it is a nice (short) exercise

Comment: Is there another way to do this without sylow´s thms?